# ContentObservers onChange is not getting called

Tags: android, gps, settings, contentobserver

I am trying to check if there is a change in gps settings. The onChange is not being called.

```
contentResolver.registerContentObserver(setting, true, new ContentObserver(handler) {
        @Override
        public boolean deliverSelfNotifications(){
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
            super.onChange(selfChange);
        Log.d("onChange","in.");
        }

        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
            super.onChange(selfChange, uri);
            Log.d("onChange","in.");
        }
    });
```

The Handler is called by

```
    Looper looper = Looper.getMainLooper();
    Handler handler = new Handler(looper);
```

The uri used is

> Uri setting = Settings.Secure.getUriFor(Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE);

Comment: did you read `LOCATION_MODE` docs?

Comment: You mean [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) ?

Comment: i mean: *"Note: do not rely on this value being present in settings.db or on ContentObserver notifications for the corresponding Uri. Use MODE_CHANGED_ACTION to receive changes in this value."*

Comment: You opened my eyes.

Comment: its not a good idea to write any code with closed eyes... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

So,Here is what I did as [pskink]{https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink} pointed out
Instead ob using the content observer used a BroadcastReceiver to listen to LocationManager.MODE_CHANGED_ACTION